# Make grep exit 1 if found, and exit 0 if not found

Tags: grep, find, make, stderr

I'm creating a simple command to execute within GitHub Actions, which builds a Makefile and returns an error if found (matching `Error 1`) and success when not found...

I seem to either get it to fail even though there is nothing wrong, or not fail when there is something wrong.

Here is my whole command:

```bash
find . -name "Makefile" -exec sh -c 'cd "$(dirname "$0")" && make' {} \; | grep -zqvE "Error 1"
```

I want it to `exit 1` if it finds an output like this:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [compile] Error 1
```

Or `0` otherwise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```bash
! find ...as in the question... | grep -qF 'Error 1'
```

The initial `!` causes the pipeline's exit status to be negated.  The exit status of the pipeline is the exit status of the `grep` command, which is zero if the string `Error 1` is found in the output of the `find` command.

Thus, if `Error 1` is found in the output, `grep` exits with zero exit status, and the `!` inverts that to a non-zero value.

Note that `make` may write diagnostic messages to its standard error stream, in which case you have to redirect the output with `2>&1`:

```bash
! find ...as in the question... 2>&1 | grep -qF 'Error 1'
```

Also note that `grep` will terminate as soon as it finds a match, causing `find` to terminate due to receiving a SIGPIPE signal as soon as it tries to write to the dead pipe.

---

You tried to use `grep` with `-v`.  You can think of `-v` as the question "Are there lines not matching this pattern?". In this case, there *will* be lines not matching `Error 1`, regardless of whether `Error 1` occurs.

Comment: Yeah ok I see what you mean, but now when it errors it still returns true. When all is OK, nothing is logged, which is to be expected, but when it errors, I get the Makefile `make: *** [compile] Error 1` message, but a status of `0`

Comment: Ah all good, I had to add `2>&1` for it to work. Cheers :)